# Массив объектов (или int) в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Делаю проект интернет магазина. У меня есть сущность "продукт", который может быть разных цветов. Я предполагаю, что нужно хранить ICollection<> доступных цветов, но не знаю как это правильно реализовать.

Сущность Product

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Category Type")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Я думал добавить таблицу attribute, в которой будет (id, type, valueId, productId)
А также attribute_value (id, value)
пример:

```
attribute:         id=1, type=color, valueId=1, productId=1
attribute:         id=2, type=color, valueId=2, productId=1
attribute:         id=3, type=size,  valueId=3, productId=1
attribute_value:   id=1, value=FFFFFF | белый цвет
attribute_value:   id=2, value=000000 | черный цвет
attribute_value:   id=3, value=36/42  | размер 36/42 eu/rus
```

И все 3 attribute добавить в поле ICollection (или IEnumerable<>) product с Id=1, чтобы потом получать цвета и размеры из Product.Attribute.

Насколько это правильно и какое решение будет адекватным?
Проект создавал на ASP .NET 7, Entity Framework 7.0.12

Comment: посмотрите тут https://code-maze.com/efcore-how-and-when-to-use-tpc-inheritance-mapping Вероятно это Вам поможет

Comment: Вариантов реализации может быть множество. Но нужно больше информации от вас. Будут ли добавляться цвета в рантайме? Будут ли одинаковые цвета (сущности цвета) у разных товаров? / Также укажите, какую именно РСУБД используете.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov , хочу сделать так, чтобы цвета подгружались вместе с товаром и были как круглые значки на карточке товара ( в каталоге, например). А на странице товара будет выбор цвета для добавления в корзину. Репозиторий на гитхабе лежит, если не сложно, гляньте, пожалуйста) любые замечания мне будут полезны мне) - https://github.com/HardfeigN/Access

Модели находятся в Access_Models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для цветов можно создать создать обычный Enum и добавить его обычным свойством (а если не хватает, то сделать struct)

```
   public enum Colors   {
 [Display(Description = "Белый", ResourceType = typeof(Globalization.Colors))] 
White = 1,

[Display(Description = "Черный", ResourceType = typeof(Globalization.Colors))]
Black = 2,
}

 public class Product{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
public Colors Colors { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: В некоторых случаях это подойдёт. Но в enum нельзя добавлять цвета в рантайме. И как теперь динамически указывать, какие цвета доступны, а каких нет на складе?

Comment: в enum заранее можно добавить все возможные цвета. Динамически указывать какие на складе есть можно только на форме через оператора.